# Make the number of line of an overflowing text dynamic depend on available vertical space

Tags: html, css, card

[This my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeXHG.png)

Let's say I have a card. The card has three parts: header, body and footer (like in the picture). In the body I want to show only some amount of text from the full content and add an ellipsis at the end.

I know we can do this by using `webkit-line-clamp` and `overflow: hidden`. However, the problem with this approach is we can set the number of lines with a specific number only. When the card header's height is small, it will make the card's height shorter than other cards in the same row. I want the number of lines to dynamically fit the card's height evenly. Can I get this effect by using only CSS? If not, what is the best approach to do it?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        /* .body-content {
            display: -webkit-box;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
        } */
    </style>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="header-content mb-3">
                            <h4>This is Header Text 1 This is Header Text 1 This is Header Text 1 This is Header Text 1</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="body-content mb-3">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus ex laborum repellendus esse itaque velit quam, quisquam et! Similique officiis dignissimos eligendi? Nihil quidem inventore ad minus! Aliquid, dolore laudantium.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer-content">
                            <h6>This is Footer</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="header-content mb-3">
                            <h4>This is Header Text 2 This is Header Text 2</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="body-content mb-3">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus ex laborum repellendus esse itaque velit quam, quisquam et! Similique officiis dignissimos eligendi? Nihil quidem inventore ad minus! Aliquid, dolore laudantium.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer-content">
                            <h6>This is Footer</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you had put your code in, we could have something to play with...

Comment: @Salketer Ok, I already added.